# Get the first column of 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, flatten

I have two numpys arrays:

```
true_values = (464, 1, 1)
pred_values = (464, 1, 4))
```

I want only to extract the first diminstion values (464) from the both arrays as I want to compare the rows of the first diminstion of the both arrays.

I've tried to do so:

```
trues_values[0,:,-1]
```

.
But it gives me only one value not 464

Comment: maybe you meant `trues_values[:, 0, -1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stef mentions, you need to slice your array differently.

```
trues_values[:, 0, -1]
```

Each of the values mean:

- `:` select all the elements in the first dimension
- `0` select the first element in the second dimension
- `-1` select the last element in the third dimension